# Цвет бара не меняется командой setStatus bar

Tags: android-sdk, android, java, android-studio, activity

[image: adasd]

Как поменять цвет status bara с черного на зеленный?
Чтобы так, как на рисунке было. Самый верхний бар, где Время, батарея, WiFI, bluetooth?

setStatusBar не меняет его.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setStatusBarColor%28int%29

Comment: @Suvitruf,

    Я писал getWindow.addGFlag
    FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS | FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS

После запуска получаю ошибку на эту строку

Comment: Какую ошибку? Что за телефон? Какая версия Android? Используете support library?

Comment: @Suvitruf.
    
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS| WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

        getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));


      java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.view.Window.setStatusBarColor
            at    com.example.SiteStat.InputActivity.onCreate(InputActivity.java:44)


Показывается на 

         getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));

Lenovo API 17, да jar и либа cupport appcompar 7

Comment: ещё раз "какая ошибка"? лог покажите

Comment: Он есть в sdk, но ваш телефон его не поддерживает, так как там Android до версии 5.0

Comment: @Suvitruf, И зачем его придумали, если он только в 5 верссии есть?)). Я удивляюсь адроидам. Когда в ИОС такое уже давно есть и даже лучше... А есть ли возможность использовать в старых версиях возможности новых АПИ? Типо на 13 АПИ адроид использовать 21 АПИ функции?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пишу сюда, так как комментировать больше не могу.

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` потому что метод только в 5.0+ поддерживается.

> И зачем его придумали если он только в
> 5 верссии есть?)). Я удивляюсь
> адроидам. Когда в ИОС такое уже давно
> есть и даже лучше...А Есть ли
> возможность использовать в старых
> версиях возможности новых АПИ? типо на
> 13 АПИ адроид использовать 21 АПИ
> функции?.

1) Для этого есть Support Library. Google фичи из новых версий sdk делает возможным использовать в старых версиях, благодаря этой библиотеке.

2) Логично, что все возможности новых версий sdk невозможно реализовать на старых версиях.

3) Не хотел, но отвечу про iOS. Сможете использовать компоненты из новой версии в старых? Нет. Потому что Apple не думает о поддержке старых версий, так как, как правило, большинство юзеров обновляет телефон сразу по выходу новой версии OS. Почему такого нет на Android? Потому что очень много вендоров и система фрагментирована.

Comment: @Suvitruf, Вот оно знач как в ОИС то...ясно.

Comment: @Suvitruf, Я подключию Support 7, может, из-за этого его нет у меня? Вы сказали все новые фичи в supportte, какой сапорт над подлюкчить? 4 7 13 17?

Comment: Не ВСЕ фичи новые включены в Support Library. И не факт, что когда-либо будут включены.